# Derivative of the Kullback Leibler Divergence

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, information-theory

If:
  $$
H (\pi(t)|\mu(t+1)) = \sum^n_{i=1}\pi_i(t) \log \frac{\pi_i(t)}{\mu_i(t+1)}
$$

How do I interpret: $\nabla H(\pi(t) | \mu(t+1) )$?

Would it be the vector:
$$
\left ( \frac{\partial H}{\partial \pi_1},.....,\frac{\partial H}{\partial \pi_n} \right)
$$
or the scalar:
$$
\frac{d}{d t}H 
$$

Comment: If $t$ is fixed, then the former should be the correct one.

Comment: in this problem, I'm told that $\pi(t)$ evolves over time, and it's flow is defined by an ODE.. which is why I am confused, the notation $\nabla$ would imply the former..

Comment: Yes, then it makes no sense to use $\Delta$, instead it should just be $dH/dt$